# OpenStreetMap and WMS basemaps not visible using QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, wms

I'm trying to import either OSM (from XYZ tiles) or a WMS as a basemap. While my shapefiles map just fine, neither the OSM nor the WMS basemap appears in the window despite appearing in the legend. They do not show up even at scale 1:250000 or by clicking on `Zoom to layer`.

These are some of the fixes I have tried, but none have worked:

- Changing project CRS (`ESPG:4326`) to OSM CRS (`ESPG:3867`) and vice-versa
- Setting layer scale visibility
- Resetting network cache
- Manually connecting OSM with a link under XYZ tiles
- Creating a new user profile

I am using QGIS version 3.4, although I cannot check the exact version information as I am faced with an error message "**unable to get current version information from server**". I'm not sure if this is relevant to my problem.

EDIT: This is what my display window looks like
[image]

Comment: Can you see the basemaps if you add them thanks to the QuickMapServices plugin ?

Comment: Are you sure that the OSM or WMS layers are on the top - thus not covered by another layer? Can you add a scrrenshot, showing your map canvas and layer panel?

Comment: @Babel it's been added. The layers are not covered

Comment: The "unable to get current version information from server" message could be a sign that QGIS dont have full internet access (or very slow), that may explain map not appearing

Comment: What are you using to add the OSM layer?  I use the QuickMapServices plugin with "OSM Standard" and have success.  Are you using a particular URL for a layer with AddLayer/Add WMS/WMTS  ?  What URL are you using to access the OpenStreetMap tileserver?

Answer (score 1):

You coordinates field shows `142.7515,86.5322` - this is out of the map canvas. Pan the image or (even better) type `0,0` to the status bar at the bottom left of your QGIS window and type `ENTER` - the map canvas will be centered on [Null island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island) and you should see the basemap.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should've chosen a better picture. Using the coordinates (0,0) yields nothing, it is still a blank window

Comment: Type `world` to the `Coordinate` field at the bottom of your QGIS window to load the pre-installed world map: does it show up? Have you close and reopened QGIS, started a new project?